# Write regex pattern in java to work for multiple && condition

Tags: java, regex

This is pattern `^\w+\.\w+ *= *.+$` that works for `parent.child1=value11`.
This is pattern `^\w+\.\w+ *= *.+ *&& *\w+\.\w+ *= *.+$` that works for this `parent.child1=value1 && parent.child2=value2`.
Is there an easier way to write a RegEx pattern that will work for both? Even more to work for multiple && condition(`cond1 && cond2 && cond3...`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to match single ot multiple conditionals:

```sh
^\w+\.\w+ *= *\S+(?: *&& *\w+\.\w+ *= *\S+)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3mQY8/2)

Repetition in `(?: *&& *\w+\.\w+ *= \S+)*` will let me match 0 or more occurrences of your conditions thus allowing it to match all of your desired expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This somehow works but I still have an issue. e.g. if I put $ sign after the first parent like this parent$.child1 fails as expected. but if I put the same $ sign after the second parent like this: 'parent.child1=value1 && parent$.child2=value2' it returns true

Comment: before the dot(.) there should be only word characters

Comment: Yes that's what is covered in regex as well. Does `^\w+\.\w+ *= *\S+(?: *&& *\w+\.\w+ *= *\S+)*$` work for you?

Comment: I think it works. I also start understanding some RegEx. Thanks for helping